# Hibernate does not add referential constraint when mapping Java class (Spring Boot app)

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, many-to-many

First time working with Spring Boot and Hibernate.

I'm trying to map my **User.java** and **Role.java** classes to a MySQL database in NetBeans. Everything works just fine except for one detail.

When I go to the generated tables using NetBeans' database manager interface in the  *Services* tab and try to manually add a row into `user_role` table (result of @ManyToMany), it lets me, even with no user or role created yet. I would expect it to prompt me with some error stating that the user id I'm inserting does not exist, for example.

Now, I come from a PostgreSQL/Doctrine background and that's maybe why it's a little odd to me because if I were to do this in **pgAdmin** well, that's a big no no.

Please, if this is default behavior, tell me how to override it, if not, here is my code with the error somewhere.

**User.java**

```
package hello;

import java.util.Set;
import javax.persistence.Access;
import javax.persistence.AccessType;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.JoinTable;
import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;
import javax.persistence.Transient;

@Entity // This tells Hibernate to make a table out of this class
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    private String name;
    private String email;
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String passwordConfirm;

    @ManyToMany(targetEntity = Role.class)
    @Access(AccessType.FIELD)
    @JoinTable(name = "user_role", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
    private Set<Role> roles;

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    @Transient
    public String getPasswordConfirm() {
        return passwordConfirm;
    }

    public void setPasswordConfirm(String passwordConfirm) {
        this.passwordConfirm = passwordConfirm;
    }

    public Set<Role> getRoles() {
        return roles;
    }

    public void setRoles(Set<Role> roles) {
        this.roles = roles;
    }

}
```

**Role.java**

```
package hello;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.Set;

@Entity
@Table(name = "role")
public class Role {

    private Long id;
    private String name;

    @ManyToMany(targetEntity = User.class, mappedBy = "roles")
    @Access(AccessType.FIELD)
    private Set<User> users;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Set<User> getUsers() {
        return users;
    }

    public void setUsers(Set<User> users) {
        this.users = users;
    }
}
```

If you need more info, please ask.

Comment: Can you use private Set<User> users = new HashSet<>(); and sand at user side for roles, I mean initialize Set.

Comment: Have you already created the table or Is hibernate creating it for you?

Comment: @ObiWan-PallavJha; the junction table I assume you are talking about, yes, Hibernate creates it